# Ubuntu login not working, Login always fails even if we enter the correct user name

Tags: 16.04, login, login-screen, username

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox. On boot, the screen shows black after the Ubuntu loading screen.

So I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to enter a command line login,
but when I enter my username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it shows:

```
Login incorrect
```

It does not even ask for password.

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021 so you may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: Okay David, Is there any way to fix this issue.

Comment: Search the site for what to do when lost password.